# Flask-Admin | How to fix route to the image

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have a question according to image path in Flask. 
I have a DB model Image, that contains all necessary info about image, including path - '/animals/sometype/image.jpg'.

I'm using Flask-admin module, and the problem is the wrong path to the image in editing mode.
Here's a code:

```
class ImageView(ModelView):
    edit_template = 'image_edit.html'

    def _list_thumbnail(view, context, model, name):
        if not model.path:
            return ''
        return Markup('<img src="%s">' % url_for('static', filename=('images' + model.path)))

column_formatters = {
    'path': _list_thumbnail
}

form_extra_fields = {
    'path': form.ImageUploadField('Image', base_path='static/images', url_relative_path='images/')
}
```

For column formatters path is correct, but for the extra fields is wrong,  resulting in 404 error: http://127.0.0.1:5000/static//animals/birds/the_bird-wallpaper-1366x768.jpg

How can I solve this? 
Also, I was thinking about passing an image to the custom edit template, but I don't understand, how to do it in Flask-Admin.

Comment: In what URL is the image? Is it in the static folder? Can you access the image from any path? That's the path that could be useful to know.

Comment: All images are at the root of the project in 'static/images' and many folders in 'images' directory.

Comment: so going to 'http://localhost:5000/static/images/folder/image-you-know-exists` does actually show the image, correct?

Comment: Correct! But path generated from form.ImageUploadField returns localhost:5000/static//animals/... without 'images' folder between two slashes.

Comment: What happens if you include a trailing slash in `base_path`? Does the filename (or the image path) include a leading slash?

Comment: Image path includes leading slash but looks like 'base_path' ignores everything inside it. I've tried to use something like 'some/path/to/image' inside 'base_path' but 404 error doesn't include any path used in 'base_path'.

Comment: Did you change anything so that the filename includes a leading slash? If not, this could be a bug. The way the paths are being constructed (as far as I could check anyway), if the path includes a leading slash, it's taken as an absolute path, so it isn't actually being `join`ed with base_path. Again, I could be mistaken as I could've checked the code more extensively.

Comment: Path in a DB already includes leading slash. base_path simply ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to pass an image to the edit view in Flask-admin without ImageUploadField. The solution is simple, all I need is to pass an image id from DB and use it in Jinja template.

```
class ImageView(ModelView):
edit_template = 'image_edit.html'

@expose('/edit/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_view(self):
    id = request.args.get('id')
    self._template_args['image'] = db.session.query(Image.path).filter(Image.id == id).first()[0]
    return super(ImageView, self).edit_view()
```

And HTML template:

```
{% extends "admin/model/edit.html" %}
{% block body %}
  <img src=/static/images/{{ image }}/>
  {{ super() }}
{% endblock %}
```